# How to capture a frame in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, animation, mfc

I have a video file in my Project. 
When I am playing it in my application, I want to capture it `frame by frame` using `Animation Control` in `MFC`.

Regards

Comment: It would help to describe what you have done so far, why you are using an Animation Control, etc. rather than letting us guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason to do this in 2011, but since you asked: you use Animate_Seek() for each frame, and use GetDC() / BitBlt() to capture an image ('screenshot') of the control for each frame.